# Two kinds of section numbering in latex article

Tags: sectioning, numbering

I want to number the sections by integers and the appendix sections with alphabets. How to use both kind of section numberings?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using? Have you tried adding `\appendix` just before you start your appendices? Can you show a mock-up of your current setup in the form of a [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/5764)?